# Disable bluetooth auto-connect for specific headphones

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, headphones

I have two different bluetooth headphones paired with my macbook. Let's call them headphone X and Y. Headphone X is my primary headphone. From time to time I use both of them in a multi device configuration. But most of the time headphone Y is used by another macbook. If I am using headphone X and then someone start using headphone Y it auto-connects to my macbook and I have to manually disconnect it in order to keep using headphone X. This is pretty annoying since I only want to use headphone Y when I manually switch my audio output to multi-configuration.
Now I was wondering if it is possible to disable the bluetooth auto-connect of my macbook for headphone Y specifically ?